# Stuck with twitcurl

Tags: c++, twitter, openframeworks

this question has gone back and forth a bit as I have learnt some things about g++ about unix systems (sorry if I messed anyone about).

For a project I am currently trying to finish I would like to get [twitcurl](http://code.google.com/p/twitcurl/wiki/WikiHowToUseTwitcurlLibrary) running with Xcode and OpenFrameworks. If anyone has managed to do this please share with me this arcane feat.

Below is some of the things I am stuck on:

Regurgitating some of the instructions from their wiki it says to

- download the libraries source
- build twitcurl library using visual C++ or make (their is also cmake in their).
- Include twitcurl.h and curl headers in your twitter application and link to twitcurl.lib and libcurl.lib/libcurl.dll.

This seems simple enough but when I make the library, there is no `twitcurl.lib`. A different file `libtwit.a` is produced, which I assume must be what OSX needs (as installing puts it in `usr/local/` along with the headers). However then if I try to include the `twitcurl.h` in a header and make a twitCurl object I then get more undefined symbols

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"twitCurl::~twitCurl()", referenced from:
  testApp::setup()     in testApp.o
"twitCurl::twitCurl()", referenced from:
  testApp::setup()     in testApp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
```

I now am assuming twitcurl makes for a 64bit (I have tried adding CFLAGS=-m32, but it fails), and to my knowledge Openframeworks is only 32 bit currently. This means twitcurl may not be an option for me, but again, if anyone knows how please let me know!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a few quick suggestions for writing questions: You should get to the actual question as quickly as possible (not five paragraphs in). You should include the actual, word-for-word error messages you received, not paraphrases of them. Finally, you should not apologize for asking a question: this is a Q/A site after all!

Comment: Hello, thanks for the advice, I just changed it around. Made the question last night in some frantic state of mind, hence the poor question. But hey, thanks again.

Comment: How does it fail with `-m32`?

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably do well to recompile twitcurl, last I looked (3 months ago), it was compiled with VC6, which has its own way of mangling C++ symbols, so the lib won't link correctly for g++.

you could then just import it directly as well and then not need to worry about linking to the libs, however it would be a good idea to test in a small demo app, before integrating into an already build system, that way you know if the error is on your side or somewhere else.

Also, when it comes to this type of problem, the *exact* compiler errors are more helpful than just describing the problem.

Comment: Hmm, that you for the heads up there. I think this would be the best approach, and have since pulled all the relevant c++ files into a new directory to compile again. I reworded the question, which will hopefully now make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you've posted is the linker's longwinded way of telling you that its looking for a definition of the `curl_easy_setopt` function, which is part of libcurl. Adding `-lcurl` to your `g++` line should fix this (by telling the linker to link in libcurl).

However, twitcurl comes with a Makefile, which already does this. In addition, if you are trying to build a shared library there, you're doing it wrong...

Comment: Hello again, thanks for clearing that up for me (I really have no idea what is going on when trying to use g++, I have only done higher level scripting). So I reformatted my question, again, but have more or less figured out twitcurl is not an option. Thanks for your time though dude.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try ofxTwitter, an openFrameworks addon for twitter, to get your twitter functionality. get it here: http://forum.openframeworks.cc/index.php/topic,2750.0.html